# How to change chunked upload filename from "blob" to another value?

Tags: coldfusion, plupload, coldfusion-2018

After a recent installation of update 4 to ColdFusion 2018 which stopped the ability to have file uploads with no file extension, Plupload chunked file uploads no longer work.

I am providing the filename and name for the multipartparams for BeforeUpload in the preinit event, but I am still seeing the following in the data being sent to the server:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

When I upload a file below the chunk size, the filename is the proper filename and the "Uploads with empty file extensions are not allowed" error does not appear.

I am looking for an option to set the value that Plupload uses for chunking, so I can add a dummy file extension. Outside of changing the Plupload libraries directly I have not been able to find an option available (or I am just blind).

Answer (score 0):

Having custom name for the blob is only possible for multipart uploads (*[multipart](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Options#multipart) option should be set to `true` - default*) and then you can set [file_data_name](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Options#file_data_name) property to a custom value.

Comment: Is there any option to change the filename on the headers? I tried that option and ColdFusion still didn't like it. It changed it as follows when I added the option in my javascript to have the file_data_name to be file.chunk.

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"

to

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file.chunk"; filename="blob"

Comment: @noble6 - This thread mentions it's just [how HTML5 works](https://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=5205#p5205) and isn't specific to that library.

Comment: Well that would certainly explain it. Sucks that Adobe didn't think of that scenario when they added their upload protection in updates 3 and 4 of ColdFusion 2018.

Comment: @noble6 - Yeah.  You might want to file a report at http://tracker.adobe.com . See what they have to say - or if there are any plans to change it in one of the updates.